# Mocking Vue method external async call to test it

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Trying to test a `Vue` component method that has external API call as well as response that returns a Promise I am trying to mock. This is what I have after removing other details:

```
    Component.vue 

    import UserAPI from '../../mixins/UserAPI'

    export default {
       mixins:
          UserAPI
       ,
       methods:

          AddUserInfo(id){     

            if (this.$options.cachedUsers.length === 0 || (!this.$options.cachedUsers.map(u => u.userId.includes(id))
            {        
               this.fetchUserById(id)   <--this is a call I am trying to mock
               .then( user=> {
                   if (user)
                   {
                       this.$options.cahedUsers.push(user);
                   }
               }) 
               .fail( errors => {
                   throw Errors(error)
               });
            }
            return this.$options.cachedUsers.find(el => el.id === id);
         } 
}

Component.spec.js

     it('should add users', () => {
        wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers = [];

        const response = { userId: "5ebdae27eb5311e0f7d2f511", userName: "admin", displayName: "Administrator" };
        wrapper.vm.fetchUserById = (id) => {
            return {
                then: () => jest.fn(usr => wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers.push(response)),
                fail: () => jest.fn(errors => { })
            };
        };
        status = wrapper.vm.AddUserInfo(user);
        expect(wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers.length).toBe(1);
 });
```

But, I am gettting an error from test runner: `this.fetchUserById(...).then(...).fail is not a function`, which means I am probably not mocking it correctly. What do I need to modify to make this test green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods are mocked the wrong way because they return functions. In order to be chainable, methods should return `this`, this needs to be done without arrows:

```
{
    then: jest.fn(function (usr) {
      return this;
    }),
    fail: jest.fn(function (errors) { ... })
}
```

It doesn't make sense to do `wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers.push(response)` in mocked method because this is already done in original method.

`fetchUserById` seems to return jQuery deferred, the result could be mocked with a deferred. The latter behaves similarly in most cases but requires to rename `catch` to `fail`. The problem with `AddUserInfo` is that it doesn't return a promise (deferred), which is an antipattern. It should be:

```
AddUserInfo(id){             
  return this.fetchUserById(id) ...
}
```

And:

```
const deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(mockUser);
wrapper.vm.fetchUserById = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(deferred);
wrapper.vm.AddUserInfo(user);
await deferred;
expect(wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers.length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! That is exactly what `fetchUserById` is returning - `jQuery deferred`, it's an old implementation. The problem with making caller `AddUserInfo` async, i.e return `$.Deferred` is that it has some additional logic I skipped for brevity - it checks if the `user` is in `wrapper.vm.$options.cachedUsers`, and if it is it will return just that object. If not, or cache is empty, it will make a call to user api, `fetchUserById`, add results to an array and then get object from array and return it

Comment: I suppose you can alternatively do `const deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(mockUser)` then. Since deferreds are thenable, I expect it to work the same way with `await`.

Comment: If you do caching, try to a reference to a promise/deferred as internal property, e.g. `this._userRequests[id] = this.fetchUserById(id)...`. You can benefit from at least for testing, but also potentially for component logic to avoid multiple requests. Any way, this can be solved without returning a deferred, updated.

Comment: Yeah, not http caching, just an array of users. But, problme, this method is a combination of sync and jQuery `$.Deferred` depending on whether the user is found or not. Updated question

Comment: I see. The use of `this._userRequests[id]` would allow to not do multiple simultaneous requests to same endpoint because they would be useless. But not critical for testing in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the point - to avoid repetitive endpoint calls. This method is polling, so running within `setInterval` evey 20 secs , so it would be expensive to have. Does it affect the test?

Comment: It affects but not this one. Test AddUserInfo in one test. Then in another test stub it and check that it's called as expected with setInterval. That's the case for Jest fake timer.

Comment: Yes, I have a separate test for `setInterval` method. I'll try to mock api call like you described above.

Comment: Now I am getting error `cannot read property fail of undefined`

Comment: What exactly do you try?

Comment: Tried out your initial suggestion: `
    then: jest.fn(usr => {
      return this;
    }),
    fail: jest.fn(errors => { ... })
} `

Comment: They shouldn't be arrows, as the answer explains, this was lost during copy and paste, fixed it. Also, this snippet is for reference only, it's much better to use real deferred/promise, as shown later.

Comment: Modified the caller logic so it returns deferred (promise) now, and modified test itself, but now getting `this.fetchUserById(...)then(...).fail is not a function`

Comment: Did you try it with `Promise`, did you? It seems that doing this would require to modify prototype chain which isn't a good thing. I'd expect it to work with a real deferred.

Comment: I am getting it with `Promise`. When trying with `.Deferred` getting this error: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error`. Looks like it's just timing out

Comment: Test started working as soon as replaced `await deferred` with `wrapper.vm.AddUserToCache.then(function(){....} etc.` Looks like you can't `await` on `$.Deferred` like you do with `Promise`. You gave me some good ideas and I appreciate your effort!

Comment: I expected `await` to work with deferred as is, but it may have better chances to work as `await deferred.promise()`.

Comment: It's just an old app that uses jq promises, I would never opt for that myself